# Python, sorting formatted output

Tags: python, sorting

I've written a short program that reads a text file containing the names of horror movies I like, their release dates, and how I rated them(each separated by a colon). It then prints each title, the release date, and my rating in a formatted output using str.format(). What I'd like to know is how I could sort the output, say by release date or rating. Here's something of what I have:

```
with open('filename', 'r') as fh:
    for each_line in fh:
        (title, date, rating)=each_line.split(':')
        print('{0:^40} {1:^10} {2:^7}'.format(title, date, rating)
```

I'd just like a hint on how I can introduce sorting into the formatted output; I just can't seem to figure it out. I'm new to Python and teaching myself, and this simple--I'm sure--problem has stumped me.

Any hints would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I would suggest that you sort the list before formatting or printing anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't print them while looping through them if you want to *sort* them: you obviously have to know every value before you can sort.

I would suggest first loading the contents of the entire file into a list:

```
movies = [each_line.split(':') for each_line in fh]
```

You can then sort by whichever key you want. To sort by the rating:

```
sorted_movies = sorted(movies, key=lambda m: int(m[2])) # add reverse=True to sort descending
```

Note that you will need to convert to `datetime` to properly sort by date.

You can then loop through these sorted movies and print:

```
for movie in sorted_movies:
    (title, date, rating) = movie
    print('{0:^40} {1:^10} {2:^7}'.format(title, date, rating)
```

Slightly more compact:

```
movies = [line.split(':') for line in fh]
for title, date, rating in sorted(movies, lambda m: int(m[2])):
    print('{0:^40} {1:^10} {2:^7}'.format(title, date, rating)
```

Comment: That looks simple enough, but I'll have to read up on lambda usage, haven't covered that yet.

Comment: The second argument of `sorted` is just a function that returns the value to be sorted. In this case, the function is pulling the `int` value of index 2 (= rating) and sorting based on that.

Comment: Is the 'int' necessary here?

Comment: Yes, if your rating is more than 9, because `'10' < '2' == True`

Comment: @writerman74 if this answer fixes your issue, you should accept it (click the check mark next to it). That does two things. It lets everyone know your issue has been resolved to your satisfaction, and it gives the person that helps you credit for the assist. [See here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) for a full explanation.